# jQuery Droppable Hover and Active Class take Precedence?

Tags: jquery, css, droppable

I'm having an issue where I see my active and hover class being applied in Firebug, but it's not taking precedence over the existing styles.

So, if my element has background-color set, the active and hover background color don't change the element.

How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do  you apply the original background-color with a class rule ? or an id rule ?

```
.something{background-color:...}
```

or

```
#something{background-color:...}
```

i am asking this because id rules have precedence over class rules

see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#preshint for selector specificity details (*as it is called*). Id is only overridden by inline styles..

Comment: Thanks, led me in the right direction.  The active and hovered class was being applied at a lower level than the class that specified the static background color.